# In C, using a pointer to a struct to call a function pointed to inside the struct leads to seg fault

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, function-pointers

I have no experience with function pointers, but I think it's something I should know, so I dove in with a simple program. I've increasingly been working in the kernel object domain, where structs and function pointers are fairly common.

This causes a seg fault:

```
int nada(int input){
    printf("value = %d", input);
}

typedef struct foo{
    void (*funcptr)(int);
}foo;

main()
{
    foo* FOO;
    FOO->funcptr = nada;

    FOO->funcptr(5);
}
```

But having a main like this instead:

```
main()
{
    foo FOO;
    FOO.funcptr = nada;

    FOO.funcptr(5);
}
```

does not cause a seg fault.

Also, I get a warning for the assignment of the function pointer:

main.c:16:17: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
     FOO.funcptr = nada;

Does anyone have an explanation?

Comment: `foo* FOO;` : It does not point to an object(of `foo` ). also `void (*funcptr)(int);` type is different.

Comment: In what way does using the typedef rather than simply declaring the variables `struct foo FOO` make anything clearer?  typedef's are great for defining complex function pointer types, but for a simple struct they are mere obfuscation.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I was just modeling one piece of what would be a more complicated and commonly-used struct type.

Comment: @aruisdante: my point is that explicitly declaring the variable type by writing 'struct foo' is far clearer.  The minimal savings in typing do not justify the additional obscurity.  This is very often a source of bugs, (eg when the typedef obscures a pointer type) for very little benefit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have

```
foo* FOO;
FOO->funcptr = nada;
```

`FOO` is pointer and you should allocate memory to it before accessing it. Without that you are accessing random memory which may produce crash.

So update code to

```
foo* FOO = malloc(sizeof(*FOO));
FOO->funcptr = nada;
```

And free the memory once used.

---

For the warning

> main.c:16:17: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default] FOO.funcptr = nada;

You have defined `nada` as function returning `int`. But your pointer to function does not return anything (has `void` return type) which is mismatch hence the warning.

Comment: Thanks! Makes total sense now.

Comment: Just a little nitpicking: Accessing uninitialized variables yields undefined behavior. The compiler may (and will) detect this and may exploit it in any way it wants. Producing code that causes a program crash is one perfectly valid result, but the compiler may as well translate it into a call to `rm -rf /`.

Comment: @datenwolf, thats why I said _may produce crash_.

Comment: @Rohan: Well, you also wrote "random memory" which is not what undefined behavior means. The compiler may just as well decide that reads from uninitialized pointer locations shall be always be done from adress `0xdeadbeef` which is definitely not random. Also keep in mind that uninitialized pointers are something different than null pointer. Reading from a null pointer also invoked undefined behavior, but with a different semantic. –– I'm not language lawyering here, but the people who write compilers do and that can turn into a problem if your program invoked undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

In your original line, this:

```
foo* FOO;
```

Doesn't create a `foo`, it creates a pointer to a `foo` that doesn't currently point to anything. You then attempt to access the non-existant `foo`:

```
FOO->funcptr = nada;
```

causing a segfalt, since that pointer doesn't point anywhere (this is technically undefined, it could do anything, but will usually segfault).

In your other example, this:

```
foo FOO;
```

actually creates a `foo` instance, so accessing/assigning its members is legal. You need to use `foo* FOO = malloc(sizeof(foo))` to create a new `foo` that is assigned directly a pointer (remember to free!), or assign the pointer to an existing `foo` instance.

Comment: Thanks! Makes total sense now.

Answer (score 0):

try this..without using malloc()

```
#include <stdio.h>

int nada(int input){
    printf("value = %d", input);
}

typedef struct foo{
    int (*funcptr)(int input);
} foo;

main()
{
    foo Foo;
    Foo.funcptr = nada;
    Foo.funcptr(5);
}
```